# Separate lines in dynamic alert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I am creating a dynamic alert, but this way the information is confusing, as I show below.

```js
var cars = [
   {id:  "1", title:  "604", nome:  "teste", respons:  "teste2", contact:  "xxxxxxxxx", Fim:  "2021-02-08", Visita:  "2021-02-08",},
   {id:  "2", title:  "604", nome:  "teste1", respons:  "teste3", contact:  "xxxxxxxxx", Fim:  "2021-02-08", Visita:  "2021-02-07",},
];

var arr3 = [];
var arr4 = [];
var arr5 = [];
var arr6 = [];
var arr7 = [];
var arr8 = [];
var arr9 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    
            title = cars[i].title;
      nome = cars[i].nome;
      respons = cars[i].respons;
            contact = cars[i].contact;
      Fim = cars[i].Fim;
            Visita = cars[i].Visita;
            id = cars[i].id;

            arr3.push(title);
            arr4.push(nome);
            arr5.push(respons);
            arr6.push(contact);
            arr7.push(Fim);
            arr8.push(Visita);
            arr9.push(id);

            if (arr3 != ''){
            
                Swal.fire('Alerta!', 'O Utente ' + arr4 + ' está em isolamento até <strong>' + arr7 + '</strong>. Necessita de alterar a visita do dia <strong>' + arr8 + '</strong>. Deve contactar ' + arr5 + ' com o seguinte número <strong>' + arr6 + '</strong> .','warning');
            }
    
            
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

In the alert, two lines are returned. When showing the alert to the user, the alert places all the information followed. My goal is that the alert shows the lines as it comes from querying the database.

Example how I want it to show information:

```
"O Utente teste está em isolamento até 2021-02-08. Necessita de alterar a visita do dia 2021-02-08. Deve contactar teste2 com o seguinte número xxxxxxxxx.
O Utente teste1 está em isolamento até 2021-02-08. Necessita de alterar a visita do dia 2021-02-07. Deve contactar teste3 com o seguinte número xxxxxxxxx."
```

That's how I want you to show the information to the user, in an organized way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're searching for?

```js
var cars = [
   {id:  "1", title:  "604", nome:  "teste", respons:  "teste2", contact:  "xxxxxxxxx", Fim:  "2021-02-08", Visita:  "2021-02-08",},
   {id:  "2", title:  "604", nome:  "teste1", respons:  "teste3", contact:  "xxxxxxxxx", Fim:  "2021-02-08", Visita:  "2021-02-07",},
];

var outputMsgArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  title = cars[i].title;
  nome = cars[i].nome;
  respons = cars[i].respons;
  contact = cars[i].contact;
  Fim = cars[i].Fim;
  Visita = cars[i].Visita;
  id = cars[i].id;

  if (title != '') {
    outputMsgArray.push('O Utente ' + nome + ' está em isolamento até <strong>' + Fim + '</strong>. Necessita de alterar a visita do dia <strong>' + Visita + '</strong>. Deve contactar ' + respons + ' com o seguinte número <strong>' + contact + '</strong> .');
  }
}

Swal.fire('Alerta!', outputMsgArray.join('<br>'),'warning');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/8.11.8/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```